# Processing .ige file in python

Tags: python, image-processing, geospatial

this is the first time I will be working with geospatial data. I downloaded that data from USDA (CropScape and Cropland Data Layer). The file is in .ige format. I reckon that it is a raster file format, but couldn't find a python library to process it. Quick search on Google did not yield anything useful. Does anyone know how to process .ige data or have a link to an example, very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

When you get the data from Cropscape, it *does* include the big .ige file as you've noted, but it also includes some other files in the zipped/tarred file that you download. One of the these is a .img. This is the one you want to open using gdal. For example:

```
from osgeo import gdal
raster = gdal.Open('2016_30m_cdls.img')
```